# MOV [SI],BX where SI is an odd offset address

Tags: assembly, emu8086

we know that the higher bank, i.e odd bank of memory in 8086 stores the upper byte of any 16-bit number.But here SI points to the odd bank already,so how does it store the contents of BX?

Comment: It's not fixed. Whatever address you provide in`SI` gets the low byte (`BL`), and the next one gets the high byte (`BH`). Doesn't matter if it's even or odd.

Comment: I don't think emu8086 simulates a real 8086 in that level of detail.  How would you tell that it uses banked memory with that arrangement, anyway?  Is there some interaction with other DMA devices you could detect with perf measurements on a real 8086, or cycle-accurate simulator?  If you ran your 16-bit code on a modern PC, memory banks would be totally different, and interleaved with at least the granularity of a 64-byte DDR burst transfer (also the cache-line size), if not a DRAM "page" (not the same thing as a 4k virtual memory page).

Comment: the memory banks are not directly visible from ASM programmer point of view (except performance implications), so the memory logically acts as big array of bytes addressable from 0 to <mem_size-1> physical address. If `si` is odd, the `[si] = bl` and `[si+1] = bh`, just in the same way, as when `si` is even. The CPU/memory controller/etc.. will handle it on x86 (although it may be a bit slower than aligned access). On some other platforms (or with some modern SSE instructions even on x86) unaligned memory access is prohibited and will be reported to CPU as failure signal.